# Remove leading and trailing whitespace on Chapters in memoir

Tags: spacing, titles

I am pretty new to Latex so apologies if this is a simple question.  I would like to reduce the amount of whitespace that surrounds a chapter title.  Here is the chapter section (please note it is a bit truncated):

```
\documentclass[twoside,9pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\chapterstyle{southall}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{Marseilles--The Arrival.}

On the 24th of February, 1815, the look-out at Notre-Dame de la Garde
signalled the three-master, the Pharaon from Smyrna, Trieste, and
Naples.
```

When it is generated it looks as follows:

[image: whitespace]

I have tried various options to reduce it all to no-avail.  Can you offer any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! No worries - also simple questions are allowed :)

Comment: Note that `titlesec` is not compatible with `memoir`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way: I copied the code for the `southall` style (section B.1.4 of [the `memoir` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf)) and modified it, giving it a new name. Adjust to suit. The package `showframe` is used just to better show the positioning of title.

Note that `memoir` provides functions similar to `titlesec`, so they're not normally used together. More information about chapter styles is in section 6.5.1 of [the `memoir` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf).

```
\documentclass[twoside,9pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example

\makechapterstyle{southall-mod}{%
  \chapterstyle{default}
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{2\baselineskip} %%%%%%%%% MOD: WAS 5\baselineskip
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{18pt}%    \headindent %%%%%%% MOD: WAS 36pt
  \setlength{\midchapskip}{\textwidth}% \rightblock
  \addtolength{\midchapskip}{-\beforechapskip}
  \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{\vspace*{0pt}} %%%% MOD: WAS 2\baselineskip
%%%  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\huge\rmfamily\raggedright}
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\huge\rmfamily\memRTLraggedright}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\chaptitlefont}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
  \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
  \renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t][\baselineskip][b]{\beforechapskip}
      {\vspace{0pt}\chapnumfont%%%\figureversion{lining}
                   \thechapter}
    \end{minipage}}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    \hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{\midchapskip}
      {\vspace{0pt}\chaptitlefont ##1\par}\end{minipage}}
  \renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{%
    \par\vspace{\baselineskip}%
    \hrulefill \par\nobreak\noindent \vskip \afterchapskip}}



\chapterstyle{southall-mod}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Marseilles--The Arrival.}

On the 24th of February, 1815, the look-out at Notre-Dame de la Garde
signalled the three-master, the Pharaon from Smyrna, Trieste, and
Naples.

\end{document}
```

[image]